# Order records from database by several values in Symfony2

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to sort a set of results in a customised order. The query does a sum of all the values in the table, and groups them by specific types. I want to sort records by the types, but this is not in an alphabetical format.

These are the values and the order I want the results to be in:

```
Prevention
Minimisation
Reuse
Recycling
Energy Recovery
Disposal
```

Here is the query I'm using:

```
    $wasteHierarchy = $dm->createQuery('
        SELECT SUM(efu.totalUom) AS totalTonne, efu.wasteHierarchy
        FROM CoreBundle:EnviroFiguresUpload efu
        WHERE efu.completionDate BETWEEN :start AND :end
        AND efu.division IN (:profile)
        GROUP BY efu.wasteHierarchy
        ORDER BY efu.completionDate DESC'
    )->setParameters(array(
                'start' => $ds,
                'end' => $de,
                'profile' => $divisionProfiles
    ));

    $wasteHier = $wasteHierarchy->getResult();
```

I've tried this query, but it throws an error in Symfony2:

```
        $wasteHierarchy = $dm->createQuery('
            SELECT SUM(efu.totalUom) AS totalTonne, efu.wasteHierarchy
            FROM CoreBumysql order by resultndle:EnviroFiguresUpload efu
            WHERE efu.completionDate BETWEEN :start AND :end
            AND efu.division IN (:profile)
            GROUP BY efu.wasteHierarchy
            ORDER BY efu.wasteHierarchy = :prevention, efu.wasteHierarchy = :minimisation, efu.wasteHierarchy = :reuse, efu.wasteHierarchy = :recycling, efu.wasteHierarchy = :energy, efu.wasteHierarchy = :disposal'
        )->setParameters(array(
                    'start' => $ds,
                    'end' => $de,
                    'profile' => $divisionProfiles,
                    'prevention' => 'Prevention',
                    'minisation' => 'Minimisation',
                    'reuse' => 'Reuse',
                    'recycling' => 'Recycling',
                    'energy' => 'Energy Recovery',
                    'disposal' => 'Disposal'
        ));

        $wasteHier = $wasteHierarchy->getResult();
```

Any ideas?

***EDIT 1***
This is the error that Symfony2 generates:

> [2/2] QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 260: Error: Expected
>   end of string, got '='
>
> [1/2] QueryException: SELECT SUM(efu.totalUom) AS totalTonne,
>   efu.wasteHierarchy FROM CoreBundle:EnviroFiguresUpload efu WHERE
>   efu.completionDate BETWEEN :start AND :end AND efu.division IN
>   (:profile) GROUP BY efu.wasteHierarchy ORDER BY efu.wasteHierarchy =
>   :prevention ASC, efu.wasteHierarchy = :minimisation ASC,
>   efu.wasteHierarchy = :reuse ASC, efu.wasteHierarchy = :recycling ASC,
>   efu.wasteHierarchy = :energy ASC, efu.wasteHierarchy = :disposal ASC 
>   +

Comment: Can you post the errors Symfony throws.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL you can only order by column, not by column value.
That's the reason for the QueryException.

There is the possibility to do what you want in mysql (possibly in other dbms as well): ORDER BY FIELD

Answer (score 0):

this part of `SQL` is wrong:

```
ORDER BY efu.wasteHierarchy = :prevention, efu.wasteHierarchy = :minimisation, efu.wasteHierarchy = :reuse, efu.wasteHierarchy = :recycling, efu.wasteHierarchy = :energy, efu.wasteHierarchy = :disposal
```

you cant set values in `ORDER BY` clause. Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp), it explains how to properly use `ORDER BY`. `ORDER BY` is followed by `ASC | DESC` keyword.

All those parameters you're trying to add maybe you should move them to WHERE clause, [check this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) for more info.